# Issue with NOW() in pdo statement

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to set the status of an employee in a database based on a date (y-m-d). If it was two weeks ago, and they set a limit of 1 week to do something, the status should change. I was doing that with this:

```
$newsql = "update csvdata set status =:newstatus where statuschangedate < NOW() - INTERVAL :atf DAY AND username =:mem";
                $newgetcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($newsql);
                $newgetcsvuser->execute(array(':newstatus' => $newStatus, ':atf' => $memATF, ':mem' => $csvusername));
```

For some reason when I run this it won't work.  Confused on why not?

EDIT:

so if I add `echo "working";` at the end of this is will say error on my page, internal error.

EDIT:

Here is the entire thing...

```
$date = date("Y-m-d"); 
$newStatus = "Non-Active - Driver Chose Non-Compliance";

    $sql = "SELECT username,ATF FROM members";
    $getcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $getcsvuser->execute();
    while($row = $getcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $memusername = $row['username'];
        $memATF = $row['ATF'];

        if ($memATF != 0 || $memATF != "0")
        {


        $tsql = "SELECT username,status,memberview ,statuschangedate,customernotes FROM csvdata WHERE memberview =:user";
        $tgetcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($tsql);
        $tgetcsvuser->execute(array(':user' => $memusername));
        while($trow = $tgetcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $csvstatus = $trow['status'];
            $csvusername = $trow['username'];
            $csvdate = $trow['statuschangedate'];
            if($csvstatus == "Open" || $csvstatus == "Enrolled - Policyholder Follow-Up Required" || $csvstatus == "Enrolled - Employee Follow-Up Required" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Insurance Cancelled" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active, Unable to Monitor - Incidental Business use Exclusion" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Employee Not Covered Under Listed Policy" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - PolicyHolder Cancelled Additional Interest")
            {
                $notes = $trow['customernotes'];
                $notes = $csvstatus . " - ATF. " . $notes;

                $tsql="UPDATE csvdata SET customernotes=:notes =:date WHERE username=:tusername";
                $tsth=$DBH->prepare($tsql);
                $tsth->execute(array(':notes' => $notes,':tusername' => $csvusername));

                $newsql = "update csvdata set status =:newstatus where username =:mem and statuschangedate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :atf DAYS)";
                //$newsql = sprintf('update csvdata set status =:newstatus where statuschangedate < NOW() - INTERVAL %d DAY AND username =:mem', $memATF);
                $newgetcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($newsql);
                $newgetcsvuser->execute(array(':newstatus' => $newStatus, ':atf' => $memATF, ':mem' => $csvusername));
                echo "working";
                $ynewsql = "update csvdata set statuschangedate =:date where username =:mem";
                $ynewgetcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($ynewsql);
                $ynewgetcsvuser->execute(array(':date' => $date, ':mem' => $csvusername));


            }


        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can elaborate a bit on "won't work"? Error message?

Comment: So it's not doing what you expect. What is it actually doing?

Comment: Nothing okay look at edit

Comment: Get a proper error message with http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right, you can't use parameters for INTERVAL .. DAY with PDO (I might be mis-remembering though).

If so, you'll have to sanitize it with `intval()` or whatever, and include it in the raw SQL.

e.g. sanitizing with `sprintf('%d')` to force `$memATF` to integer:

```
$newsql = sprintf('update csvdata set status =:newstatus where statuschangedate < NOW() - INTERVAL %d DAY AND username =:mem', $memATF);
```

Comment: It should work with interval ... day but not with interval ... days

Comment: so wait I am confused how do I execute this with what I have?

Comment: Just the same, just remove `:atf` from your execute statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$newsql = "update csvdata set status =:newstatus where username =:mem and statuschangedate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :atf DAYS)";
```

I would change this row: (because this could mean that $memATF could be NULL or a string)

```
if ($memATF != 0 || $memATF != "0")
```

to:

```
$memATF = intval($memATF);
if ($memATF >0)
```

This would make sure that $memATF has to be an integer and the code will move on if integer is larger then zeo.

Comment: try adding another ) at the end :)

Comment: What are the actual values of $newStatus, $memATF and $csvusername ?

Comment: You can't be sure of the actual values... Echo out values of variables ($newStatus, $memATF and $csvusername) before the sql is executed, and then do an exit() just for debugging purposes. OR :Where you create your $DBH-variable, set this parameter... $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Answer (score -1):

Hey guys I fixed it it was because: `$tsql="UPDATE csvdata SET customernotes=:notes =:date WHERE username=:tusername";` notice the `...:notes =:date....` so I just took out the `=:date` and it works perfect now :)